# Visual Studio Team Services account issue

Tags: azure-devops

I'm TFS admin, I'm trying to add none hotmail account to Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) but it seems that members can't recieve invitations, is that possible to add none hotmail accounts in VSTS.

Thank you

Comment: Which email address do you use? I tested with a .gmail email address and a .126 email address, both can receive invitation.

Comment: Are these none hotmail account registered as Microsoft Account?

Answer (score 0):

You must add email addresses for ["personal" Microsoft accounts](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/account/default.aspx) unless your Team Services account [uses your organization's directory](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-account-users-assign-access-levels-team-services#ConnectedDirectory) to authenticate users and control account access through [Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis). If your users don't have Microsoft accounts, have them [sign up](https://signup.live.com/?uaid=8852c08630514254b5181329870d2e88&lic=1).

If your Team Services account is connected to your organization's directory, all users must be directory members and sign in to Team Services with "work or school accounts" that are managed by your organization's directory. If they're not members, have a directory administrator add them to the directory. That way, you can find them in this directory when you add users by searching for their email addresses or display names.